# How can I change the version of apache on OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, apache

The default version of apache is 2.4.9.  I downloaded 2.4.10 from apache website and "make & make install". However, when I do httpd -v, it still shows me 2.4.9.

Is there a way to change the default version or override?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing

```
which httpd
```

to see the full path to the one that you are running. Mine is `/usr/sbin/httpd` - the standard one shipped with OS X.

Then check which directory you installed your new httpd into - probably `/usr/local/bin`. So the problem is not that it is not installed, but that OSX is looking at a different httpd from the one you installed.

To use the one that you have installed, you need to edit the file `/usr/sbin/apachectl` and find the line that says:

```
HTTPD='/usr/sbin/httpd'
```

and change it to point to wherever you installed your new apache.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is more of I have two versions of Apache on my system. I have been making symlinks in /usr/bin/ but failed because I did not use absolute path in my ln command.